# How to embed a user control (with a form) into SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a user control with a form, and I am trying to embed it in sharepoint 2007... I am getting an error about having two server-side forms on one page. This is crazy! Surely I can write a user control with a form and embed it in sharepoint??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually nothing to do with SharePoint - it an ASP.NET question so it may help to change the tags.

[MSDN - Form-based Programming in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx)

> One of the most common snags that ASP
>   developers encounter when they first
>   approach ASP.NET is that managed Web
>   applications **must be written according
>   to a single-form interface model**...the
>   SFI model is so entrenched in ASP.NET
>   that there's no way around it.
>
> In this column, I'll review
>   programming forms in ASP.NET and
>   discuss ways to implement a multi-form
>   programming model.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am now just using the SharePoint form instead, which works fine.